# Response.Flush with HTTP/2

Tags: asp.net, iis, safari, http2

**Background**

In a version of Safari that supports HTTP/2 (i.e. v9+) running on macOS “El Capitan” v10.11 or newer, when accessing a webpage served from IIS10 via HTTP/2 (e.g. Windows Server 2016 / Windows 10), if the page contains a "Response.Flush" then it will not load. It simply hangs with a white screen. Web server CPU usage also spikes during these occurrences.

This [thread](https://forums.iis.net/t/1235574.aspx?Response+Flush+not+working+on+SSL+site+in+classic+ASP) suggests that when Response.Flush is used, IIS switches protocol from HTTP/2 back to HTTP/1.1. Safari cannot handle this, whilst all other browsers seemingly can.

Demos from the link above:

*Working* - http://limoeventplanner.com/safari-test.asp

*Not working* - https://limoeventplanner.com/safari-test.asp

I appreciate that the solution to this problem may lie elsewhere (I currently have a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=173719) open with webkit), so I will try to make my questions focused...

**TL;DR**

1. Does using Response.Flush still make sense in a HTTP/2 environment?
2. Is the "downgrade" to HTTP/1.1 by IIS the expected behaviour in this scenario? If so, why?

Comment: I accessed both working and non working url from chrome 57.0.2987.110 to test the behavior,i got http 1.1 for both ?

Comment: As explained above, when using Response.Flush IIS seemingly downgrades to 1.1, so that's to be expected. Safari can't seem to cope with this.

Comment: HTTP/2 protocol switching starts with an upgrade header send to the IIS server and IIS does not have much control on this as this is handled at the http.sys layer.

 Since the issue seems to be with Safari,we can do a work around from the
 server side to avoid the issue I hope. Before the application calling
 Response.Flush,we can check the browser user agent,OS
(**HTTP_USER_AGENT**) and the HTTP version by checking the server
 variable **SERVER_PROTOCOL** and then avoid the call to Response.Flush

Comment: We got exactly the same problem with Firefox. Worse, the response.flush bug happened after a POST request, so we got a double postback, which IMHO should never ever happen. We are disabling HTTP/2 for this application.

Comment: @LeandroBarone: How did you disabled HTTP/2 for you application? I am getting exactly same issue.

Comment: @BrettPostin : How did you manage to open http://limoeventplanner.com/safari-test.asp  page on HTTP 1.1?

Comment: @MayurLohite we disabled HTTP/2 to resolve the issue in the short term. The longer term solution was to refactor calls to Response.Flush. The issue is seemingly resolved in Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: @BrettPostin: I would like to know how you disabled HTTP/2 ?

Comment: @MayurLohite Depends on your webserver but for IIS https://stackoverflow.com/a/31714461/295813

Comment: @BrettPostin: Thanks!