# Disable Http2 on Windows Server 2016 at Site Level

Tags: http2, windows-server-2016, iis-10

Anyone know if there is a way at the site level to disable HTTP/2.0 on Windows Server 2016?  Disabling server-wide is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but I had hard time to find proper answer my self, so I'm answering here for reference.

On Windows Server 2016 you can only disable HTTP/2 server-wide (how to do it is described here: [How to disable HTTP/2 on IIS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31668151/151960)).

Windows Server 2019 added added flag for control of HTTP/2 per site:

- In IIS Manager right click on site.
- Click *Edit Bindings...*.
- Select https binding and click *Edit...* or click *Add...* if such binding doesn't exist.
- Check *Disable HTTP/2* checkbox.