# Disable HTTP2 For Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, http2, alpn

Is it possible to disable `HTTP2` in the edge settings or in the profile?

Or maybe is it possible to disable `ALPN`?

Comment: Not found method to disable Http/2 in the Edge setting, but you could try to [disable Http/2 on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668151/how-to-disable-http-2-on-iis-10)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help : (