# ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY on latest Microsoft edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge

My website runs perfectly in the edge browser originally shipped with Windows 10.

However, I installed the latest edge browser from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) & it started giving me the below error as `ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY` & my website is not opening.

For Firefox, I could use `about:config` & disable http2 in the configuration manager. Is there a setting which can be done for new edge browser as well ?

This is an internal site so i am fine with disabling the settings.

Comment: Not found method to disable Http/2 in the Edge setting, but you could try to [disable Http/2 on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668151/how-to-disable-http-2-on-iis-10). Besides, if your application is asp.net core application, please check these similar issues: [issue 1](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/16434) and [issue 2](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14350).

Comment: the server infra is not in our control & it is not dot net core. it is Angular

Comment: When using the Microsoft Edge Legacy versions whether set some setting to make it work well (such as disable http2)? Can you try to debug your code and check which part of code will show this error? Then, share this part of code to reproduce this issue, it might be easier for us to help you solve the problem.