ASP.NET Core - Disable HTTP/2 on HttpSys
I have a server that I'm migrating from .NET 4.8 (ASP.NET + OWIN) to ASP.NET Core 8. For reasons, I have to use HttpSys instead of Kestrel.
One difference I've noticed during this migration is that by default ASP.NET Core has HTTP/2 enabled, and uses it, while .NET 4.8 always downgrades to HTTP/1.1.
The problem is that HTTP/2 prohibits renegotiation necessary to retrieve client certificate which is then used by some of the endpoints.
Is there a way to force ASP.NET Core + HttpSys to use HTTP/1.1? (e.g. disable HTTP/2).
From what I read on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-8.0

In a future release of Windows, HTTP/2 configuration flags will be available, including the ability to disable HTTP/2 with HTTP.sys.

And unfortunately, this day hasn't come yet.
So, how does .NET 4.8 notify HttpSys that it doesn't support HTTP/2 (and thus downgrades to HTTP/1.1)? Can the same thing be done with ASP.NET Core?
I need a solution that only applies to this specific app, and not a device-wide config/registry changes that would be applied globally.

You should probably find a way to remove the renegotiation, because TLS1.3 and HTTP 2 and 3 are the way forward.

I don't think even the WINAPI functions offer this as an option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/http/

@Charlieface I wonder how net48 AspNet is forcing http.sys to drop HTTP 2 support then?
I know that going forward a proper solution with HTTP 2 and 3 needs to be done.
But for the time being, dropping support for HTTP 2 would be the easiest way to keep the same behavior as net48 application that's been working so far.

I'm not sure but it's dependent on the version of Windows and the version of .NET you have. What are the version numbers?

windows 11, framework installed is "4.8.09032". But afaik, net48 does not support HTTP2 for compatibility reasons regardless of versions.

Does ASP.NET classic even use HTTP.sys? I'm not sure it does. I think it uses IIS.

If you don't mind disable HTTP/2 for all typical applications on this Windows, you can apply a few global changes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668151/how-to-disable-http-2-on-iis-10

If you want to modify the tls version to disable the tls 1.2, I suggest you could try to modify the registry by using this path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL.

UPD: Please read the second part of the answer.
The trick is that .NET Framework 4.8 supports HTTP/2 (it's oblivious of the HTTP version) and never explicitly downgrades the HTTP version in the request.
The httpapi.dll HttpReceiveClientCertificate function does the magic:

if HTTP/2 is used, HTTP.sys sends the HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED (0xD) error code
The client must renegotiate the TLS session but in the ALPN extension it must request HTTP/1.1 only
The client (curl in my case) opens a new TCP connection to the host
HTTP.sys negotiates HTTP/1.1 and does not ask for a client certificate because there is no correlation between 1st and 2nd session.
The client sends the request, application logic is called 2nd time, and it asks for the client's certificate
This time HTTP/1.1 is used so HTTP.sys renegotiates the TSL session asking for the client certificate
Your application receives the client certificate

To achieve the same behavior in .NET you have to call HttpReceiveClientCertificate directly (you'll have to get the RequestQueueHandle & ConnectionId via Reflection), or by calling the internal .NET function (also via Reflection) - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.Request.GetClientCertificateAsync.

Okay, now I have information to answer your question directly. Just use this command (get ipport, certhash and appid values from netsh http show sslcert output):
netsh http add sslcert disablehttp2=enable disablequic=enable ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=e202ab04495430cbef1921f6c493765e7e942e43 appid="{00001111-aaaa-2222-bbbb-3333cccc4444}" 

I've been told that these two options, although not documented, will work even on updated Windows Server 2016. I checked them myself on Windows 11 & Windows Server 2022.
And there is another, programmatic way to do it, use HttpSetServiceConfiguration function from http.h, with HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_SET, which should use HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_PARAM to turn on the HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_FLAG_DISABLE_HTTP2 flag.
I've found the API info here.
